# Valor en arreglo se repite

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un código en c++ que debe encontrar si las palabras de un arreglo `palabras` se encuentran en un arreglo `diccionario` y devolver si la palabra está y en qué posiciones. Para esto hice este código:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
/*
5
En
Casa
De
Lalo
Casa
4
En
Casa
Lalo
Los
*/
struct estado{
    string palabra;
    string esta = "NOESTA";
    int posicion[3] = {-1, -1,-1};
};

void verifica(string palabras[], string dict[], int n, int m, estado encontrado[]);
int main(){
    string palabras[100];
    string diccionario[100];
    estado encontrado[100];
    int n, m;
    cout<<"Ingrese numero de palabras en la frase: ";
    cin>>n;
    for(int i = 0; i< n; i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese palabra de la frase: ";
        cin>>palabras[i];
    }

    cout<<"Ingrese numero de palabras en el diccionario: ";
    cin>>m;
    for(int i = 0; i< m; i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese palabra del diccionario: ";
        cin>>diccionario[i];
    }

    verifica(palabras,diccionario,n,m,encontrado);

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<"Palabra: "<< encontrado[i].palabra<<", Estado: "<< encontrado[i].esta;
        for(int j = 0; j<3; j++){
            if(encontrado[i].posicion[j] != -1){
                cout<<", Posicion: "<<encontrado[i].posicion[j];
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

void verifica(string palabras[], string dict[], int n, int m, estado encontrado[]){
    int itr = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< n; i++){
        itr=0;
        for(int j = 0; j< m; j++){
            encontrado[i].palabra=palabras[i];
            if(palabras[i]==dict[j]){
                encontrado[i].esta = "ESTA";
                encontrado[i].posicion[itr] = i;
                itr++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Para este enunciado:

> Búsqueda
> Se quiere buscar unas palabras en un diccionario para este fin se cuenta con una serie de palabras almacenadas en el vector `palabras` de tamaño `n`, una palabra puede repetirse máximo 3 veces.
> Adicionalmente se cuenta con una lista de palabras ya definidas en un vector diccionario, contra las cuales se va a comparar cada palabra de la frase por verificar.
> El vector diccionario tiene tamaño `m`.
> Usted debe crear una función que verifique si una palabra se encuentra o no en el diccionario.
> Como resultado de la verificación la función genera un arreglo de estructuras `estado` que debe contener la palabra de la frase, el estado de la verificación y la posición donde se encuentra la palabra en el vector palabras.
> Si la palabra no se encuentra debe colocar la posición de la palabra representada con un valor negativo.
> En este vector `estado` que se crea no puede existir una palabra más de una vez.
> Cada palabra de la frase tendrá un estado de verificación como resultado de la comparación contra el diccionario.
> El estado de la verificación puede ser una de las siguientes opciones:
>
> - "ESTA" si la palabra coincide exactamente con alguna del
>   diccionario
> - "NOESTA" si la palabra no aparece en el diccionario.

El cual testeé con el comentario que sale al principio. Y el resultado fue este:

```
Palabra En, Estado: ESTA, Posicion: 0
Palabra Casa, Estado: ESTA, Posicion: 1
Palabra De, Estado: NOESTA
Palabra Lalo, Estado: ESTA, Posicion: 3
Palabra Casa, Estado: ESTA, Posicion: 4
```

Funciona bien, sin embargo al repetir una palabra, como en este caso "Casa", sale dos veces; es decir, crea otra posición en el arreglo.
Su comportamiento normal debería ser que sólo salga una vez "Casa" y que en `posiciones` salga 1, 4.
Aquí un ejemplo visual de como debería quedar:

[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: Evidentemente te falta una función que evalué la ocurrencia de una palabra, si esa ocurrencia es menor a 2 la puedes ingresar en el array de `palabras` y debe ser cero para ingresarla al de `diccionario`. r

Comment: Esto ya te lo resolví en la pregunta anterior

Comment: Tu problema no es un error en el  código, es de lógica. Tu array `encontrados` tiene que tener **una sola estructura por palabra** pero en ningún momento te encargas de comprobar si una palabra ya esta agregada a este array. La aproximacion mas obvia es  recorrer tu array de palabras, por cada una compruebas si ya existe su estructura en `encontrados`, si existe simplemente  agregas su indice al array del campo `posicion`, si no existe el struct en `encontrados` aun, "creas" uno nuevo  para la palabra, lo agregas a `encontrados` y buscas si esta en el diccionario para completar el campo `esta`